# Add custom product fields to WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In the past, I've added custom fields to my products in WooCommerce. This was only visible at the back and not directly visible on the front end.

Now I can't get it done in any way. When I work with plugins, this only works on the product page as a selection. But I would like to configure it on the product page in the back for example after the regular price field (see example).
[image]

I'm looking for the right hooks to do this. Anyone have an idea where I can find this?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_pricing', 'add_custom_fields_to_poduct_general');

function add_custom_fields_to_poduct_general() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
            array(
                'id' => '_custom_text',
                'value' => get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_text', true),
                'label' => __('Custom text', 'woocommerce'),
            )
    );
}
```

Add more fields after price using the hook `woocommerce_product_options_pricing`

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_custom_product_field');

function save_custom_product_field($post_id) {
    $key = '_custom_text';
    $value = (!empty($_POST[$key]) ? wc_clean(wp_unslash($_POST[$key])) : '' ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.NonceVerification

    if ($value) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, $key, $value);
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($post_id, $key);
    }
}
```

The hook `woocommerce_process_product_meta` is used to save the data added using the above hook